# Bigger logarithmic color scale Python sns.clustermap()

Tags: python, seaborn, figure

Most of my values in pivotted lie between 0.96 and 1.. like
0.960186
    0.960139
   0.960129
etc.. I want them to be distinctishable.. but as some of my values are much more greater like 10, I did a double logarithmic colorscale.. But this doesn't help. Has someone an idea?

[image]

I did

```
p = sns.clustermap(pivotted, norm=SymLogNorm(linthresh=0.000000001, vmin=pivotted.min().min(), vmax=pivotted.max().max()))
```

Comment: Hi @Anja, I tried the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192121/custom-color-palette-intervals-in-seaborn-heatmap

Comment: It should work for your data, as long as you adjust the boundaries, the bar is ugly. Maybe you can try it.. If you have problems i can post a solution below..

Comment: @StupidWolf that would be so kind

Comment: I tried p = sns.clustermap(pivotted,  cmap='gist_ncar', linewidths=0.2) .. But as I want to see differences between 0.96 and 1 ... I still cant see anything :(

Comment: sadly it didnt help.. I dont get the boundaries def.. My data look like: 0.964, 0.967, 0.976, 0.998, 10 (the 10 is just there instead of nans, because I couldnt cluster with nans, so I decided to chose a big number, that is then outside the cluster.. maybe I need another idea for that problem)

Comment: hmm maybe you can set them to max(matrix) + 1.. then use the boundary. note the boundary must run from 0 to 1. and what it means is imagine you log values scaled from 0 to 1. 10 would be at 1 and 0.9 would be between 0 to 0.1

Comment: looks better, thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below, the trick is to set the boundaries at the lower values:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

boundaries = [0.0, 0.03, 0.06, 0.09, 0.12,1.0]  
hex_colors = sns.color_palette("coolwarm", n_colors=len(boundaries) * 2 + 2).as_hex()
hex_colors = [hex_colors[i] for i in range(0, len(hex_colors), 2)]

colors=list(zip(boundaries, hex_colors))

custom_color_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    name="cus",
    colors=colors,
)
```

You can also define a list of colors as long as the boundaries. So below i try to simulate data like yours, don't know how close it is:

```
np.random.seed(111)
df = np.random.uniform(low=0.8,high=1,size=(8,8))
df[np.random.randint(0,7,6),np.random.randint(0,7,6)] = 10,9,10,9,10,9

sns.clustermap(df,norm=LogNorm(),cmap=custom_color_map)
```

[image]